# transparent blur fixed block with css

Tags: html, css, filter, blur

I'm trying to make a transparent fixed header **without JS but only CSS**.
I have an example where used `::before` to make blur substrate with negative `z-index`.

https://jsfiddle.net/VeryDeepSky/w8a93wpu/

But I've just failed... so many times... Meanwhile, I already know how to do it with *jQuery*. I'm looking for CSS solution. Can someone help?

Thanks!

P.S. here what I'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/VeryDeepSky/81f7wcwh/6/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: OK. @Paulie_D here what I'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/VeryDeepSky/81f7wcwh/6/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for background image but I don't know how apply blur effect to all the elements under the header.

```css
.content:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG');
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.content {
  background-image: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
}
p:first-child {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend
    rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing,
    quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
  <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum
    tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: nice! thanks, for helping! and what you thinking about placing links in a blurred block? I'm trying make a top with nav.

Comment: "I found a solution for background image" -- where did you find it from? Please include citation/link so OP can reference it to get more info.

Comment: I found by myself, testing differents ways.

Comment: @IvanVoitenko the blur filter applies to an element and its content, isn't a mask that affects what lies beneath. My idea is to use th e same background and apply the blur as in the example I put.